# How to install Mapr client on windows 7 64bit?

Tags: window, mapr

I am trying to install mapr-client in window 7 64bit with  [link](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Setting+Up+the+Client#SettingUptheClient-windows-client)

- I'm go to set java and mapr path both after that download the setup
  and extracted while executing the below command getting an error.

> server\configure.bat -N my.cluster.com -c -C node01:7222.

Have
   changed it like below.

```
server\configure.bat -N Mapr.konexy.com -c -C 10.0.3.13:7222.
```

- Below is the error that i am getting

> 'c:\opt\mapr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MAPR_HOME variable pointing to c:\opt\mapr, where the mapr client zip is extracted.